# Save file in directory of executing file

Tags: python

I have a directory (data) that contains a file `get_raw_data.py`.
`get_raw_data.py` has a function to save a file.

A file present in some other directory (`stock_prediction`) imports this function and runs it.

The file gets saved in the `stock_prediction` directory.

How do I save the file in `data` directory?
(`stock_prediction` has a child directory `dashboard` which has the child directory `data`)

I could use absolute path but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the path relatively to a file where this code is present i.e. if your file is `hello.py`, the `__file__` will be its location:

```py
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

path = join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), "folder", "file.txt")
print(path)
```

Example:

```py
# if run from get_raw_data.py
print(__file__)                                        # get_raw_data.py
print(dirname(abspath(__file__)))                      # "data" folder
print(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), "output.txt"))  # output.txt in "data"
```

and based on that you can navigate anywhere if you have a permission to access/write to such location.

Also you can utilize [`os.makedirs(dirname(path))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create such a location if it has folders not yet present and then write to it:

```py
with open(path, "w"):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank u Peter! 
Should I use abspath or realpath?

Comment: @AniketBanyal I'd say that's a matter of a use case. If you don't have any symbolic links realpath() might be an overkill.